# Insert column values from another table: multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables with the following structures:

Table1

```
ID   Temperature  Channel
```

Table2

```
ID   Thickness  prime  value
```

I want to add the column 'value' to Table 1 from table 2 such that table1.id = table2.id. I have altered table1 and added the column value to it. But when I execute the following query, I am getting an error:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (value)
    SELECT value 
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```

The error I am getting is:

> The multi-part identifier "table1.id" could not be bound.

What changes should I make to this code to make it run successfully?

Comment: You need to specify both tables in the `FROM` clause

Comment: When I do that, I get this error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table table1; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: In your description `table1` has no column `value` yet you list in the targeted columns of the `INSERT`. And I suspect you rather want an `UPDATE` than an `INSERT` anyway. But since your question tells what you really want to do, that's just a guess. So [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE TABLE` statements of the tables, `INSERT INTO` statements with sample data for them and the expected result with that sample data as tabular text.

Comment: I have altered table1 and added the column Value. I have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @Jenna the error you get means  `table2.value` has a `NULL` but `table1.value` is non-nullable. That doesn't mean that JOIN is wrong. You *have* to use JOINs. If you want to exclude null values add `WHERE table2.value is not null`

Comment: @Jenna; Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

It is Update with join, not an insert (If you have records on table1):

```
UPDATE Source
SET 
    Source.[value] = [Target].[value]
FROM table1 as Source
INNER JOIN table2 as [Target] ON Source.id = [Target].id
```